# Best practices: editing sshd_config over ssh

Tags: ssh

I've recently needed to update my `sshd_config` file as the [`hmac-ripemd160` MAC is no longer supported as of `sshd` version 7.6](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6).

I edited the file then ran:

```
sshd -t
```

to test the config.

When that returned null output and exit code `0`, I reloaded the config via:

```
kill -HUP $(pgrep -f /usr/bin/sshd)
```

(The [man page](https://manned.org/sshd) says `sshd` rereads its configuration file when it receives a hangup signal, `SIGHUP`)

---

What are the best practices when changing a server's `sshd` configuration over an `ssh` connection?

Comment: The most important practice is that you always have a secondary way of logging into the machine if things go bad. So for a VPS, make sure you have console access through your ISP/Hosting company. For a physical machine, make sure you're near it and have a keyboard nearby. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can log in after making changes before dropping privilege and logging out is my best practice.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Oldskool says](https://serverfault.com/questions/884594/best-practices-editing-sshd-config-over-ssh/884636#comment1140732_884594), ensure you have another way of accessing the machine (console, NX, teamviewer).

Instead of editing the default config file, make a copy and then run:

```
sshd -t -f <new-config-file-name>
```

to test the new configutation.

Try the configuration on an unused port (thanks to @gf_ for this tip):

```
    sshd -f <new-config-file-name> -p <unused-port>
```

Note that `-p` overrides `Port` configuration, but `ListenAddress` config will override `-p`.

When you can login, copy the new config over the old (after making a backup).

Then have the server reload config:

```
kill -HUP <PID of sshd>
```

Comment: Also: Change the port in the copied config you're editing, start another `sshd` instance using this config, verify that the connection works (if allowed via the firewall), your changes are in place and working as expected.